# how can i click button to create page selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

The option is selected but a button does not click to create a page

```
formElement.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-primary btn-block']")).click();
```

---

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" onclick="registerUser()">Create</button>
```

Comment: I tried this also    formElement.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='addUserModal']/div/div/div[3]/div/div/button[1]")).click();

Comment: What is the error that you are getting and is you have used `formElement` so your driver name is `formElement` ?

Comment: I think formElement is form web element and stores a form with subelements.@SameerArora

Answer (score 0):

if you use `WebDriver driver;` then below snippet will helps to you.

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-primary btn-block']")).click();`

Answer (score 0):

I think problem's cause is class name with empty spaces. It is common issue when you work on `reactjs` or `angularjs` projects.

I hope this can solve your issue, please refactor your code as following :

```
formElement.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.btn.btn-primary.btn-block"));
element.click();
```